# mod-rewrite to strip out sub directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

How would I rewrite a URL such as:

```
http://www.site.com/sub-directory/page-name
```

to

```
http://www.site.com/page-name
```

?

Comment: the answer depends on whether you want **every "sub-dir"**  to be stripped out or only when the file exist

Comment: Yes, I would like every first sub directory to be stripped out. For instance if the current path is http://www.site.com/sub-directory/sub-sub-directory/page-name I would like http://www.site.com/sub-sub-directory/page-name

Comment: is `sub-directory` a static directory? If not how would you deal with naming conflicts??

Comment: My issue is because I am running 3 different sites from the same CMS. I have each of the sites loading fine from their domain names however each of the pages on the sites are being output at domain.com/site-name/page-name. I just need to remove the site-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your intended solution is using [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html), but if you don't have access to the httpd.conf, you can try the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host1.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/host1-dir
RewriteRule ^(.*) host1-dir/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host2.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/host2-dir
RewriteRule ^(.*) host2-dir/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host3.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/host3-dir
RewriteRule ^(.*) host3-dir/$1 [L]

# If doesn't match any of it then 404 Not Found or anything you like
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host1.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host2.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =host3.example.com
RewriteRule .* - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC mod_rewrite supports regex, so you can use it's replace:

```
^(.*/)[^/]*&
```

The parens match all up to last `/`.

Then you re-use it using group reference, I think it's `$1`. The rest is dropped.

Check mod_rewrite help on how to use regexp.